# Wireless on an Acer Aspire 1810T with an Intel 5100AGN works for less than a day, then stops working until reboot

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, intel-wireless

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on an Acer Aspire 1810t with an Intel 5100 AGN wifi card that has performed flawlessly on Ubuntu 10.04. I assumed the stellar wireless support would continue with 12.04 but have run into a glitch that is a showstopper: wireless works as expected at first, and I can configure connections with Network Manager without any problem, including my WPA2-Personal home network, but after some time (usually a number of hours, almost always after a suspend-to-ram or hibernate) the wireless connection drops and is unable to reconnect. The only reliable solution is to reboot, which is not a solution. Before opening a bug on Launchpad, I thought I'd check and see if anyone else has managed to resolve this problem. Here's what I've got:

Problem: wifi in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit stops working on the Acer Aspire 1810t (Intel WiFi 5100 AGN) after some time, often after a suspend-to-ram.

**$ uname -a**

```
Linux ubuntubox 3.4.0-030400rc5-generic #201205011817 SMP Tue May 1 22:18:19 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

(note: the problem is the same when running the stock 3.2.0 kernel)

**$ dmesg**(at the time the connection drops)

```
[54671.300096] wlan0: authenticate with 00:24:7b:6d:32:62 (try 1)
[54671.301874] wlan0: authenticated
[54671.304312] wlan0: associate with 00:24:7b:6d:32:62 (try 1)
[54671.308760] wlan0: RX ReassocResp from 00:24:7b:6d:32:62 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[54671.308766] wlan0: associated
[54681.808039] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[54692.009142] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:24:7b:6d:32:62 by local choice (reason=3)
```

**$ sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: WiFi Link 5100
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.4.0-030400rc5-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 ip=192.168.0.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:44 memory:d2500000-d2501fff
```

**$ sudo lspci -v**

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at d2500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

**$ cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**$ sudo rfkill list all**

```
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
7: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
8: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

**$ tail -f /var/log/messages**(resuming, dead wifi)

```
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.244181] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.260253] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.276244] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.280511] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.280794] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.600255] PM: suspend of devices complete after 323.607 msecs
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.600259] PM: suspend devices took 0.324 seconds
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.600492] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.228 msecs
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.616373] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.632226] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.632286] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.632345] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.632521] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.7: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.648212] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.648281] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 47.784 msecs
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.648929] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.649057] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.650636] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.652187] CPU 1 is now offline
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.652845] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.652845] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.652845] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.652845] Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.668170] CPU1 is up
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.671401] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.793414] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.793500] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.7: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.793817] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.793886] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.793954] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.794037] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.794755] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 1.559 msecs
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.794994] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.177 msecs
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.795387] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.795615] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.795665] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.795713] usb usb6: root hub lost power or was reset
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12683.798755] power_supply BAT1: parent PNP0C0A:00 should not be sleeping
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12684.040051] usb 2-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12684.120062] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12684.124050] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12684.132111] ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.196167] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.215180] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.228167] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.249349] PM: resume of devices complete after 3454.346 msecs
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.249624] PM: resume devices took 3.456 seconds
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.249848] Restarting tasks ... done.
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.316278] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.518981] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.555609] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.555618] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.555627] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.555635] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.555642] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.555650] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.555657] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.563241] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.563249] Copyright(c) 2003-2012 Intel Corporation
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.563435] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: pci_resource_len = 0x00002000
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.563442] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: pci_resource_base = ffffc900051fc000
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.563449] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW Revision ID = 0x0
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.570648] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 8.83.5.1 build 33692
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.571146] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.571152] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.571158] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.571164] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TESTMODE enabled
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.571170] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_P2P disabled
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.571178] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN, REV=0x54
May  8 05:44:05 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.571285] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
May  8 05:44:06 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.604278] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x11f, CALIB=0x4
May  8 05:44:06 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.604289] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Device SKU: 0xF0
May  8 05:44:06 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.604296] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Valid Tx ant: 0x2, Valid Rx ant: 0x3
May  8 05:44:06 ubuntubox kernel: [12687.604329] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 24 802.11a channels
May  8 05:44:06 ubuntubox kernel: [12688.405992] psmouse serio2: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.2, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xd04733/0xa40000/0xa0000
May  8 05:44:06 ubuntubox kernel: [12688.451546] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input14
May  8 05:44:08 ubuntubox kernel: [12689.945926] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
May  8 05:44:08 ubuntubox kernel: [12689.955185] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
May  8 05:44:08 ubuntubox kernel: [12690.082356] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
May  8 05:44:08 ubuntubox kernel: [12690.085386] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
May  8 05:44:08 ubuntubox kernel: [12690.137134] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May  8 05:44:09 ubuntubox kernel: [12690.809060] NMI watchdog: enabled, takes one hw-pmu counter.
May  8 05:44:09 ubuntubox kernel: [12690.809136] NMI watchdog: enabled, takes one hw-pmu counter.
May  8 05:44:15 ubuntubox kernel: [12696.651391] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.656253] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.674667] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.674670] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.674675] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.674680] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.674685] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.674689] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.674693] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.677556] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.684066] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.735617] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.887209] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.890478] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12701.939523] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May  8 05:44:20 ubuntubox kernel: [12702.437321] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
May  8 05:44:28 ubuntubox kernel: [12710.154644] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
May  8 05:44:48 ubuntubox kernel: [12730.051190] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May  8 05:44:48 ubuntubox kernel: [12730.062972] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
May  8 05:44:48 ubuntubox kernel: [12730.062975] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
May  8 05:44:48 ubuntubox kernel: [12730.062980] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:48 ubuntubox kernel: [12730.062984] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:48 ubuntubox kernel: [12730.062989] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:48 ubuntubox kernel: [12730.062994] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:44:48 ubuntubox kernel: [12730.062998] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```

**$ sudo tail -f /var/log/messages**(killing wifi with hardware switch, turning back on)

```
May  8 05:53:49 zephyr kernel: [13271.516713] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
May  8 05:53:50 zephyr kernel: [13271.819483] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
May  8 05:53:50 zephyr kernel: [13271.822543] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
May  8 05:53:50 zephyr kernel: [13271.875392] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May  8 05:53:57 zephyr kernel: [13279.570132] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
May  8 05:54:18 zephyr kernel: [13300.056967] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May  8 05:54:18 zephyr kernel: [13300.066622] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
May  8 05:54:18 zephyr kernel: [13300.066625] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
May  8 05:54:18 zephyr kernel: [13300.066630] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:54:18 zephyr kernel: [13300.066635] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:54:18 zephyr kernel: [13300.066639] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:54:18 zephyr kernel: [13300.066644] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:54:18 zephyr kernel: [13300.066648] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
May  8 05:54:25 zephyr kernel: [13306.917810] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
May  8 05:54:25 zephyr kernel: [13306.918640] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
```

### Troubleshooting

- cannot connect to Open APs or WPA2 APs
- once the network problems start, plugging in a USB WiFi adapter w/ Atheros chipset results in the same problem with both cards. This USB device is known to work with Ubuntu "out of the box", suggesting it is not an iwlwifi driver problem.
- disabling "N" mode does not work: "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" in /etc/modprobe.d/disable11n.conf
- no option to use ndiswrapper for this wifi card (which is probably a good thing!)
- unloading iwlwifi before suspend does not work: SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES iwlwifi" in /etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules
- switching to kernel 2.6.39 (with iwlagn driver), 3.3.0, 3.4.0rc5 does not work
- removing the acer_wmi module (sudo rmmod acer_wmi) does not work, and disables bluetooth
- "sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart" does not work
- "sudo stop network-manager && sudo start network-manager" does not work
- "sudo rmmod iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi" does not work
- deleting the connection in Network Manager and recreating it from scratch does not work
- using wicd to manage the network doesn't work

Any ideas?

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour for my ThinkPad X200's intel 5100 AGN card. I also tried the same troubleshooting procedures and none worked. Is there any launchpad bug related to this issue? (It would be best to report it there).

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/996205

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I have similar issue with the only exception that even restarting the box does not work, only solution so far is restarting the modem itself.

Comment: I remember on 12.04 the solution consisted in downloading a specific proprietary driver for that model.